Replacing parbox with a box in mathmode
Context: I have been developing a series of macros for constructing (admittedly rudimentary) diagrams in multicategories; see below for the kind of diagram that I mean.
In the following, I use \parbox to control the horizontal and vertical sizes of boxes around text and tikz drawings to achieve a particular arrangement. However, since \parbox formats in paragraph mode (obviously), the arguments of my macro will not appear in math mode as I would like unless I manually surround each with a math environment. Here's a MWE and a screenshot of its output: My actual macros allow for other cases besides the binary case, but this is illustrative.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\twidth}
\newlength{\lbuffer}
\newlength{\rbuffer}
\newlength{\fullwidth}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tight}{m m m m}{% Custom macro for binary multimaps.
 % The intended syntax is \tight{NAME}[ARG1][ARG2]{COD}
 % where:
 % NAME is the label that will appear within the morphism shape;
 % ARG1 and ARG2 should be either atomic input symbols such as $A$
 % *or* further instances of \tight{...};
 % COD represents the codomain of the morphism
 \settowidth{\twidth}{$A$}%
 \settowidth{\lbuffer}{#2}%
 \setlength{\lbuffer}{\lbuffer*\real{0.5} - \twidth*\real{0.5}}%
 \settowidth{\rbuffer}{#3}%
 \setlength{\rbuffer}{\rbuffer*\real{0.5} - \twidth*\real{0.5}}%
 \settowidth{\twidth}{#2~#3}%
 \setlength{\twidth}{\twidth - \lbuffer - \rbuffer}%
 \assemble{\twidth}[\lbuffer][\rbuffer]{#1}[#2~#3]{#4}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tdraw}{m m}{% NAME,\twidth
 %Triangle long side up.
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {#1};
  \draw (0,0) +(0,-18pt) -- +(-0.5#2,6pt) -- +(0.5#2,6pt) -- +(0,-18pt);
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\assemble}{m O{0pt} O{0pt} m m m}{%\twidth, \lbuffer, \rbuffer, NAME, ARGS, DOM
  \setlength{\fullwidth}{#1 + #2 + #3}%
  \parbox[b]{\fullwidth}{%
   \centering%
   \parbox{\fullwidth}{#5}\\
   \makebox[#2]{}%{
   \makebox[#1]{\tdraw{#4}{#1}}%
   \makebox[#3]{}\\
   \vspace{-3pt}%
   \makebox[#2]{}%
   #6%
   \makebox[#3]{}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\tight{$\alpha$}{\tight{$\beta$}{$A$}{$B$}{$X$}}{$Y$}{$Z$}
\end{document}


I would like to instead set up these macros to work entirely in math mode, both to avoid having to explicitly format the arguments and to enable better interactions with other math elements (such as being able to put these in an equation environment without TeX throwing a bunch of warnings at me).
In looking for a way to do this, I came across the boxes masterpost and the \mathmakebox command in the mathtools package. While the package documentation gives me the syntax for the box parameters, neither it nor the article of Alexander R. Perlis it links to say much about the intended usage, and a straightforward substitution of the \parbox for a \makemathbox in the above, so that the \assemble routine is replaced by,
\NewDocumentCommand{\assemble}{m O{0pt} O{0pt} m m m}{%(orientation),twidth,lbuffer,rbuffer,NAME,ARGS,DOM
  \setlength{\fullwidth}{#1 + #2 + #3}%
  \mathmakebox[\fullwidth][b]{%
   \centering%
   \mathmakebox[\fullwidth]{#5}\\
   \makebox[#2]{}%{
   \makebox[#1]{\tdraw{#4}{#1}}%
   \makebox[#3]{}\\
   \vspace{-3pt}%
   \makebox[#2]{}%
   #6%
   \makebox[#3]{}%
  }%
}

produces "There's no line here to end." errors, presumably because the line breaks aren't appreciated in math mode... Explanations of the different modes in LaTeX are a little thin on the ground (this doesn't give me much, for instance), so please can someone explain to me how to achieve the desired box arrangement in math mode?
Side note: I originally tried to write this macro entirely inside a tikzpicture environment with the fit package, since that has direct coordinate-wise control of elements, but I couldn't figure out how to achieve the rescaling of components to correctly vertically stack components without horizontal overlaps, and the documentation for the fit package is very light. Any suggestions on how to improve my construction would be appreciated, since I may eventually release this as a LaTeX package if I can get it working with sensible enough syntax.

just change your original to use $#6$,  $#1$ etc so you don't need 4 in the arguments of the call

@DavidCarlisle I can see how that would resolve the formatting issue within the document, but is the implication that there does not exist an effective solution for manually arranging boxes without leaving math mode?

Tex has no math mode boxes (or alignments), you always have to re-enter math mode for every box and every alignment cell, even if you hide that from the user

Just change your original to use $#6$, $#1$ etc so you don't need $ in the arguments of the call.
TeX has no math mode boxes (or alignments), you always have to re-enter math mode for every box and every alignment cell, even if you hide that from the user.

It's certainly preferable for that ugly necessity to feature in the macro construction rather than the body of the document. I may comment again here if I encounter unexpected behaviour from this solution in context. Thanks!

This solution uses \mathsbox to comvert the text to saveboxes.  This not only gives you the width, once they are formatted they don't need math mode.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,csquotes}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathstyle}% for \xurrentmathstyle
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{calc}% parsonal aversion

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathsbox}[2]{% #1=box number, #2=text
  \sbox#1{$\m@th\currentmathstyle#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\newlength{\twidth}
\newlength{\lbuffer}
\newlength{\rbuffer}
\newlength{\fullwidth}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tight}{m m m m}{% Custom macro for binary multimaps.
 % The intended syntax is \tight{NAME}[ARG1][ARG2]{COD}
 % where:
 % NAME is the label that will appear within the morphism shape;
 % ARG1 and ARG2 should be either atomic input symbols such as $A$
 % *or* further instances of \tight{...};
 % COD represents the codomain of the morphism
\bgroup
 \mathsbox0{#1}\setlength{\twidth}{\wd0}%
 \mathsbox2{#2}\setlength{\lbuffer}{\dimexpr 0.5\wd2 - 0.5\twidth}%
 \mathsbox2{#3}\setlength{\rbuffer}{\dimexpr 0.5\wd2 - 0.5\twidth}%
 \mathsbox2{#2~#3}\setlength{\twidth}{\dimexpr \wd2 - \lbuffer - \rbuffer}%
 \mathsbox4{#4}%
 \assemble{\twidth}[\lbuffer][\rbuffer]{0}{2}{4}%
\egroup}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tdraw}{m m}{% NAME,\twidth
 %Triangle long side up.
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {#1};
  \draw (0,0) +(0,-18pt) -- +(-0.5#2,6pt) -- +(0.5#2,6pt) -- +(0,-18pt);
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\assemble}{m O{0pt} O{0pt} m m m}{%\twidth, \lbuffer, \rbuffer, NAME, ARGS, DOM
  \setlength{\fullwidth}{\dimexpr #1 + #2 + #3}%
  \parbox[b]{\fullwidth}{%
   \centering%
   \usebox#5\\
   \hspace{#2}%
   \makebox[#1]{\tdraw{\usebox#4}{#1}}%
   \hspace{#3}\\
   \vspace{-3pt}%
   \hspace{#2}%
   \usebox#6%
   \hspace{#3}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tight{\alpha}{\tight{\beta}{A}{B}{X}}{Y}{Z}
\end{equation}
\end{document}


Odd numbered scratch box registers should only be used for global assignments.

@egreg -  I thougth it was even numbers, since \count0 is even and used globally.

No, \count0 is not a scratch register (and neither are \count1 to \count9), because it contains the current page number. Even numbers for local settings, odd for global ones. One can use \count0 to \count9 as scratch registers, but only locally and in situations where a page break is impossible.

It is consistent.

Playing around with this solution, it reproduces the specific example, but for higher stacks the horizontal alignment is off (my original macro doesn't have this problem), presumably because the contents of the \mathsbox es being overwritten in the middle of the construction. This could be useful for me elsewhere, though, so thanks!

@JohnKormylo That's what I said, isn't it? You can use those counters locally, provided you ensure that no page break can be triggered in the meantime.

Also no \setcounter{page} etc.
